# Firefox Dev-Tools - console not showing HTML-preview of XHR-Request anymore

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using the latest FF (108.0.1)

In the developer tools, when I submit an XHR-Request, I used to see the request's HTML-Rendering in the «Answer»-Tab of the console. This stopped working like 2 or 3 versions ago.

Now all I get is a blank page. If I switch to «unformatted» it shows the HTML-Code of the response.

When I use the «Network»-Tab, I do see the HTML Response. But the interaction with the result doesn't work anymore.
Explanation: I'm using Typo3's `DebuggerUtility::var_dump()` which creates a nice rendering of objects and arrays. I used to be able to expand the entries with a «plus»-sign, in the HTML-View of the console. Which is very handy. This is not working when I use the Network-Tab of the Dev-Tools.

Any ideas how to get that functionality back?

[image]

[image]

[image: This is the view I get from the Network-Tab]

Answer (score 0):

This bug got [fixed a few days ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1804232). That means it is working again in Firefox 110.

Though note that JavaScript was never executed in that preview because of security reasons, as far as I can tell. The output is pure HTML plus CSS like in your screenshot of the *Response* tab in the Network panel saying that JavaScript needs to be enabled.
So, the toggle there may only work if it is using a browser internal feature like the `<summary>` and `<details>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Interesting - FF tells me that I have the latest version. But the bug's still there. Maybe it wasn't fixed for the mac?

Comment: The latest release version is 108. Version 110 will be released around the 14th of February, 2023. See https://whattrainisitnow.com for more release info.

Comment: Ah - I see... again, thanks for your reply. I'll wait patiently for the release in February then.